# compressing and saving image captured to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, local-storage

I'm working on an HTML widget which will be embedded in an iBook in iBooks Author for the iPad.

I've got a simple button to trigger image capture on an iPad and all is working fine.

```
<div id="zeroDiv">
<input type="file" id="getPic" accept="image/*">
</div>
<div id="picWrapper">
<img id="image">
<div id="buttDiv">
    <button id="picButt"><span class="buttText">Insert image</span>

    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#picButt').click(function () {
$('#getPic').trigger('click');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#getPic").on("change", gotPic);
$("#image").load();
});

function gotPic(event) {
$("#image").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
$("#picButt span").text("Change image");
}
```

fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/mikawaben/cq2yrh2z/

However, when the user moves off a page and returns, the image is lost as the page reloads. I need to store the image in localStorage.

I know that the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/VXdkC/2/ (courtesy of Musa on this site) holds code which could be the key for me.

```
$('#addNote').click(function () {
var Title = $('#title').val();
var Message = $('#message').val();
var pic = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
var imgUrl;
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var imgURL = reader.result;
  $('#notes').prepend("<div class='entry'><h1>" + Title + "</h1></p>"+ "<p>" + Message + "<img src=" + imgURL + "></p> </div>");

  var notes = $('#notes').html();
  localStorage.setItem('notes', notes);
  saveDataToLocalStorage(imgURL);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(pic);
return false;
});

//show content of notes in storage
$('#notes').html(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
return false;
```

But despite messing around with it for a couple of hours, I'm not getting it to work. Can anyone lend a hand with this?

I'm also concerned about compression. Do I need to use base64 encoding or something in case the image size causes the whole thing to crash?

Comment: What is `saveDataToLocalStorage` and where do you try to redisplay the image on return?

Comment: Hi Musa... I want to display the image just above the `picButt` button. I've already got this working in my fiddle. As the `saveDataToLocalStorage` was part of the code I quoted from your fiddle, I was hoping you could tell me what it was! When the code runs, I need it to first check for an image in local storage and if there is one, to display it above the button. If not, when an image is captured to not just display this on the page but also to save it to local storage. Thanks!

Comment: above the `picButt` button = in the `picWrapper` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if there is an imaged saved on page load and display it. Then save the image when selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getPic").on("change", gotPic);
    if (localStorage['url']){
        $("#image").attr("src", localStorage['url']);
        $("#picButt span").text("Change image");
    }    
});

function gotPic(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        $("#image").attr("src", this.result);
        localStorage['url'] = this.result;
        $("#picButt span").text("Change image");
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq2yrh2z/1/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. This stores the image to localStorage and retrieves it perfectly.

Comment: However, to prevent every instance of this code using the same image, I planned to add a unique key for localStorage with a global variable thus
`uniqueID = "page1"`
...
`localStorage['url'+uniqueID]`

When I do this though, I'm able to get each instance to store a different image successfully, but the last image retrieved is always that from my photo gallery. Camera captured images only last until the page reloads and then the last photo gallery added image loads instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Idk, sounds like a closure issue. You should ask a new question though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a closure issue. I will ask another question... although it will be the third one for this code!